# Webcam not working in Ubuntu 19.10 on XPS 13 [9343]

Tags: dell, webcam, 19.10, xps, uvc

The integrated webcam has stopped working on Ubuntu 19.10 running on my XPS 13. Not sure if this was a breaking change in 18 or 19, but it definitely worked previously. Opening Cheese I just get 'No device found'.

The camera is definitely being detected by the system at least. Here's the output of `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i Camera
usb 2-5: Product: USB 2.0 Camera
uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:6362
```

And these are the `uvcvideo` errors I get on startup:

```
.. kernel: [ 1046.126651] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB 2.0 Camera (0c45:6362)
.. kernel: [ 1046.127803] uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
.. kernel: [ 1046.128289] uvcvideo: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
.. kernel: [ 1046.128293] uvcvideo: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
```

[This Dell forum thread](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Dell-xps-13-9370-Webcam-support/td-p/6032049/page/15) suggests a fix for 9370 users has been incorporated in to the kernel, but this doesn't seem to be the case for me on 9343.

Comment: I also have a xps 9343 with kubuntu 20.04, without access to my cam. No device in all applications.
I don't even get the dmesg output..

Comment: @sarbot, I also don't have any output from dmesg, did you find a solution?

Comment: no i didnt I'm using another device right now, but I'm still looking for a solution..

Comment: I also figured out that the webcam works on some webplatforms like dfnconf and discord, but not with other applications.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the solution to your problem, but I'll post it here anyway in case it helps someone else.

I have an XPS 13 9343 with Ubuntu 20.04, and the integrated webcam wasn't detected. Turned out I had to enable it in UEFI.

(Note that it had worked before, and I did not actively disabled it.)